# Is it possible to pass stages into a Jenkinsfile via pipeline parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm currently working with a Jenkinsfile I can't directly add code to as it is not developed by my team, however I was thinking there might be some way that I could get the owners of the Jenkinsfile (just another team in my company) to allow us to add "pre" and "post" type variables to the Jenkinsfile, where we could than pass in the stages and logic.

A sample Jenkinsfile today might look like

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Clean-Up WS') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
        stage('Do more....
```

And the desired Jenkinsfile might look like

```
def x = stage('Clean-Up WS') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
            }
        }

pipeline {
    stages {
        x()
        stage('Do more....
```

Where *x* in the above example could be passed in via a Jenkins parameter

I've played around with the above and tried with similar syntax but nothing seems to work

Does anyone know if anything like this possible using Jenkinsfiles?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood it right.. You want to have stage in a method and call it only when required based on the user parameter? @Kieren_M

Comment: Sorry @vijay if I wasn't clear. I basically want to pass in the function/stages as a Jenkins parameter, which is then called from the Jenkinsfile. Was just using the above as an example

Comment: you can have boolean params to execute a stage only if required right instead of complicating the flow. Run this stage Y or N, If y, then enter the stage else it skips.... Have you tried that?